# Solution of $xy\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(1+y^2)(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of $$xy\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(1+y^2)(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}$$

Please help me with this one. I have tried things like rewriting it as

$$xy\frac{dy}{dx} = (1+y^2)+\frac{(1+y^2)x}{1+x^2}$$ and then trying to collect coefficients of $y^2$ but nothing seems to be working here. Could someone suggest something?

Comment: This is separable...

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** From the first equation, you get $$\frac{y}{1+y^2}dy = \frac{1+x+x^2}{(1+x^2)x}dx$$ and then integrate both side.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) method here.

\begin{eqnarray*}
xy\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} &=& \frac{(1+y^2)(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2} \\ \\ 
\int \frac{y}{1+y^2}~\mathrm dy \ &=& \int \frac{1+x+x^2}{x(1+x^2)}~\mathrm dx
\end{eqnarray*}

The integral of the left is straight forward; you should be able to find it without any tricks.

The integral on the right is harder. For that you should use [partial fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). You will find that
$$\frac{1+x+x^2}{x(1+x^2)} \equiv \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{1+x^2}$$
where $A$ and $B$ are real constants. Once you know $A$ and $B$, you are almost done.
$$\int \frac{y}{1+y^2}~\mathrm dy \ = \int \frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{1+x^2}~\mathrm dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different (perhaps more complicated) perspective: Use a substitution.

$$xy\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{(1+y^2)(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2}$$

Try the substitution $v = 1+y^2$, and you get $\frac{1}{2}\frac{dv}{dx} = y\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Using this, we have:
$$\frac{1}{2}x\frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{v(1+x+x^2)}{1+x^2} = v\left( \frac{1+x^2}{1+x^2} + \frac{x}{1+x^2} \right) = v\left(1 + \frac{x}{1+x^2}\right)$$

Now multiply both sides by $\frac{2}{xv}$ to get:
$$\frac{1}{v}\frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{2}{x} + 2\cdot\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Next, notice that $\frac{1}{v}\frac{dv}{dx} =\frac{d}{dx}\ln(v)$, and integrating both sides with respect to $x$, we obtain:
$$\int \left(\frac{d}{dx}(\ln(v))\right)\,\text{d}x = \int \left(\frac{2}{x} + \frac{2}{1+x^2}\right)\,\text{d}x$$

---

I present this perspective because several types of ODE's are most conveniently solved using substitutions, and starting to work with them early and often can make it less daunting later.